# How ca we use add_grouping with emtrends in R to estimated marginal means of linear trends?

Tags: r, group-differences, marginal-effect

We've conducted a quasi-experiment where an intervention was available for students to use in four semesters and was not available in other four semesters in a large college-level course. Students started each semester by taking a pre-test and they ended with a post-test.

We need to analyze the effect of the intervention on the correlation between the pre-test and post-test. Obviously, the pre-test and post-test are correlated. If the intervention had no effect on students' learning, the correlation between pre-test and post-test in semesters with the intervention should not be significantly different from the correlation in semesters without the intervention. That's the main reason we need to use `emtrends` from the `emmeans` package in R.

In our regression model, we need to consider the fixed effects of each semester, but at the end of the day, we should estimate the effect of the intervention, not each semester. So, we use `add_grouping` to group semesters with the intervention under "Treatment" and those without the intervention under "Control" groups.

The main issue is that `add_grouping` returns an `emmGrid` object, but `emtrends` does not accept an `emmGrid` object. Is there any other way we can group the effects and use `emtrends`? Or is there any better method of analyzing the effect of intervention on the correlation between pre-test and post-test?

Here is our R code:

```
m1 <- lm(post_test ~ semester * pre_test + GPA + gender + ethnicity + 
    academicLevel + termCreditsGPA + parentsMaxEducation + program_Cat + 
    PubMathScore + honorsPro + international, data = d1)
m1_Grid <- ref_grid(m1)
conditions_Fact <- factor(c("Control", "Control", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Control", "Control", "Treatment", "Treatment"), levels = c("Control", "Treatment"))
m1_Grid <- add_grouping(m1_Grid, "Condition", "semester", conditions_Fact)
m1_emtrends <- emtrends(m1_Grid, revpairwise ~ Condition, var = "pre_test")
summary(m1_emtrends, adjust = "tukey", infer = TRUE, type = "response")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the trends *first* (keeping the nested factor), and do the grouping later:

```
tmp <- emtrends(m1, "semester", var = "pre_test")
conditions_Fact <- factor(c("Control", "Control", "Treatment", "Treatment", "Control", "Control", "Treatment", "Treatment"), levels = c("Control", "Treatment"))
m1_emtrends <- add_grouping(tmp, "Condition", "semester", conditions_Fact)
emm <- emmeans(m1_emtrends, "Condition")
contrast(emm, "revpairwise")
```

The reason that `emtrends()` cannot be used with an `emmGrid` object is because, in order to estimate trends, we need to use the model with slightly different values of `var` in order to construct a difference quotient.

Comment: PS - in this example, there is no need for `type = "response"` since there is no response transformation or link function. And `adjust = "tukey"` is the default for pairwise comparisons.